# How to implement SpringBoot's Retry Template in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I tried to implement Spring RetryTemplate with Kotlin but when i tried to call the method RetryTemplate.execute() then there is a compile error said that:

[image]

My code is similar to this:

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun getB(): B {
    return retryTemplate.execute { retryContext -> fooA.getB()}
}
```

Performed many searching with no hope. Could you show me an example that work in this case. Thanks

Comment: Where and how  have you declared "retryTemplate"?

Comment: @Meier the retryTemplate is a property inside my class constructor.

import org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate
class MyClass(retryTemplate: RetryTemplate) { fun getB(): B {.....} }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by specific the type of Exception inside RetryTemplate explicitly, here is what i did:

```
 fun getB(): B {
    return retryTemplate.execute(RetryCallback<B, Exception> { fooA.getB() })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can parameterise `execute` method as well:

```
fun getB(): B {
    return retryTemplate.execute<B, Exception> { fooA.getB() }
}
```